# How to exclude java classes from being compiled with annotation processing?

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I have two annotations:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Ann {
    public String description() default "AAA";
    public String template() default "BBB";
}
```

and

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface AnotherAnn {
    public String text() default "Text";
}
```

simple class with annotated method:

```
public class App {
    @Ann(description = "Desc", template = "Templ")
    public void someMethod(){}
}
```

I want to create new copy of `App` class and replace `@Ann` annotaion in the copy class (before `someMethod` method) to `@AnotherAnn`.
E.q. Copy of `App` class after annotation processing:

```
public class AppCopy {
    @AnotherAnn(text = "Text")
    public void someMethod(){}
}
```

And then I should exclude `App` class from being compiled.
Processor:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("alexiuscrow.annotation.Ann")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class Proc extends AbstractProcessor {

    public Proc() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        /* TODO CREATE COPY & EXCLUDE ORIGINAL */
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Put the java code you are trying with, give some more details.

Comment: Have you found any solution your issue. I am quite interested in it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two general approaches for excluding certain Java classes from annotation processing:

1. run the compiler twice.  The first time, compile the entire project without running an annotation processor.  The second time, the command line should include the annotation processor and should list only the files for which you want to run the annotation processor.  Only files that the compiler compiles are subject to annotation processing.  That includes files passed on the command line, plus any that those depend on whose .class files are not up to date.
2. write logic in the annotation processor to skip processing of certain files.

Approach #1 is the one I use.

Comment: You could Google "how to write an annotation processor in Java".  :-)  There are a lot of tutorials out there.

Comment: I know how to write an annotation processor but I don't know how to skip processing of certain files.

Comment: Write a Java `if` test in the annotation processor so that it does no work when specified conditions are met.

Comment: Has anyone written an annotation processor to skip files?